# Kotlin Multiplatfrom Mobile is not opening with xml layout?

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

In my android stuido, Kotlin multiplatform mobile project is automatically opening with jetpack compose but I want to open it with xml layout. How can I open it?

I want to open KMM project with xml layout, not with jetpact compose.